# number of certificates, listeners and routes in envoy proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, azure-application-gateway, envoyproxy, amazon-elb

Hi I am looking for using envoy proxy for a multi tenant saas application, where we would like to let our customers have their own domains  (kind of bring your own certificate model). 
I am currently looking at using nginx,envoy etc as our front proxy/reverse proxy.Assuming we may have 1000's of customer , i was wondering how many certificates, routes (there by customers) can each envoy proxy /nginx can support with reasonable qos(of course not defined here).
Googling around this did not yield much results, hence this post here.

Have any body tested reverse proxies  for their capability of supporting multiple certificates, rule sets etc, and if there is a degradation in performance as and when we add more listeners, certificates, routes?

Interestingly most cloud providers have some kind of limits e.g AWS one can upload only 25 certifcates per ALB, have only finite set of target groups (2k or something) and 100 odd routing rules.

Likewise Azure application gateway too has restrictions with rules, listeners etc

so does google application load balancer (100 certificates i guess).

My fundamental question is these limits on rules/ certificate etc defined for maintaining basic QOS or is it purely a commercial in nature?

Any insights/suggestions/blogs/posts/performance bench mark in this area will be of immense help for making right decision.

Comment: hey bro, did you able to find any answer for this problem?